# Migrating MacBook Pro image without Time Machine

Tags: macbook-pro, online-backup, migration-assistant

What are my options if I have MacBook Pro with lots of data and apps, and I am moving to another country for work. I do not have any external hard drive. My employer will provide me with a better MacBook pro (larger screen and overall performance) once I move and I would like to restore everything from previous MacBook Pro. I know there are cloud solutions, but is FTP one of the options? I have some great FTP servers (10s of TBs).

Thanks..

Comment: Backup anything you cannot easily replicate.  Applications settings are trivial to synchronize in today's world.  You can download and install applications in minutes.  Synchronize only the data that is time consuming.to create or cannot be created again.  It is also trivial to mount those FTP directories to behave like a network share.

Comment: I think mounting FTP as Network Drive and then using Time machine to backup to the image, as here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_VwHGSHSnDk

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to migrate *everything* from the old MacBook Pro to the new one, you should use Migration Assistant. Follow the instructions at the Apple Support page [Move your content to a new Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT204350). In a nutshell, assuming that both computers are running OS X 10.9 or later:

1. Connect both MacBook Pros to the same WiFi network OR connect them together directly via Thunderbolt or Firewire.
2. Open Migration Assistant on the *new* MacBook Pro select the first option to move your content from a Mac.

[image: OS X Migration Assistant]

See the linked support page for further details.

Comment: There is physical constraint to this. I have my MBP at location A, and I will travel without it to point B. I will get new one once I am at point B. So there is no option to connect the two...

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that you would lose the old laptop prior to moving.